# Requesting Selenium WebDriver Multiple Times

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to request Selenium webdriver.Chrome multiple times with the same URL, let's say 30 times.

I have experienced two problems when I running that using Python in Linux.

The first one, when I using webdriver.quit(), it takes long time to finish the running of an iteration even though the browser is opened, loading, and then close.

I replaced the webdriver.quit() with webdriver.close() and the first problem solved; however, I found the program stop before finishing the number of determined iteration, which is my second problem.

How could get rid of the problems and especially the second one.

Comment: Anyway you can post your code?

Comment: I think it is a buffering issue that should be resolved.